# How to preserve the size of children movieclips in a fluid scrollPane in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, resize, children, fluid, scrollpane

I'm working on an AIR desktop project.

I have a scrollPane with a container assigned to it...

```
mainScrollPane.source = mainContainer;
```

The scrollPane is resized whenever the window is resized, in order to keep things fluid (it fits under a header container, and to the right of a left container)...

```
mainScrollPane.setSize(Math.round(stageWidth - leftContainer.width), Math.round(stageHeight - headerContainer.height));
mainScrollPane.source = mainContainer;
```

I'm dynamically creating movieclips and adding each one to the container...

```
mainContainer.addChild(boxMC);
```

In my library, boxMC is set to 400 pixels wide, yet I'm finding that each boxMC is displayed much wider than that.

When I resize the window, each boxMC doesn't scale in size (good).

I'm clearly not understanding the process for creating a fluid scrollPane that can be resized while having it's contents remain the size that I've created them at in the library. Can sometime please enlighten me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was not to give mainContainer width and height settings. So instead of mainContainer.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100); mainContainer.width = 500; mainContainer.height = 200; I just made it mainContainer.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100); then added movieclip don't scale their size when mainScrollPane is resized.